# Javascript Interface between Android Activity and Apache Cordova's WebView

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

So I've already developed 80% of my app thanks to Phaser Framework, and took it to Android Studio thanks to Apache Cordova's project template that, as it seems, they have a pretty customized WebView. The thing is that I was pretty confident that to make a JavaScript Interface was going to be as easy as with the regular WebView, but it's not. I just can't seem to find the instace at which I'd do:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface();
```

And that means that I won't be able to communicate with Activity to do vital things like triggering In App Purchases or showing Chartboost Ads!!! I need some hindsight on this please, It just can't be that all of my work goes to waste. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you don't want JS interface between Android Studio (IDE) and WebView. You want JS interface between Android (Activity, Fragment, whatever, but not the Android Studio) and WebView

Comment: @VladMatvienko yeah should've clarified, thanks, I will edit

Comment: If you are using Cordova you have to use plugins, it will use the javascriptInterface internally

Comment: @jcesarmobile any plugin in particular?

Comment: No, there are a few for in app purchases, but I have not tested any. And no idea about chartboost.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that I have to make them myself. It's not hard though, I'll answer my question whenever I have time, thank you

Comment: I have made many Cordova plugins according to my requirement. First edit your question title it should be like interface between activity and js. If required I will post the answer.

Comment: @ShahbazHashmi yeah I don't find the button to edit the title. I saw all the Cordova doc about creating plugins and seems straight forward, if you get to answer the question faster then I have time to learn it then i'd be a time saver. Thank you anyways

Comment: You may never know may be a good question get many up votes. Edit your title and I will post a proper answer with activity to js and vice versa communication tomorrow. I am out of station today. Using so from phone.

Comment: @ShahbazHashmi done, thanks

Comment: Hi Joaquin, I have posted the answer. It is working I just removed other functions like "registration" from java file.

Comment: Hi Joaquin. Please accept the answer. It is working example of Cordova plugin.